# Asp.NET Core controller action returns 404 when published

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, url-routing

I have an ASP.NET Core application that uses MVC, and I recently added authentication to it.  It worked fine when testing locally, but after I published the app and installed it on another server, the login method always returns a 404 error.

The weird thing is, *only* the login method has this problem - if I open up Postman and make a request to one of the other API methods, it will return 401 Unauthorized (as expected, since I'm not logged in).  So I know I have the right URL, but it's still returning a 404.

The Login method is written exactly the same as the other methods, the only difference I can see is that it has [AllowAnonymous] instead of [Authorize] in the attributes.

The other oddity I've noticed is that it takes quite a long time (~30 seconds) before it returns a 404 error.  Requests to other controllers don't have the same delay.

None of this makes any sense - why does that method fail, when another method on the same controller gets routed properly?  Why a 404 error?  And why does it work on my local machine?

Login controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILoginService _service;
    private readonly CustomTokenOptions _tokenOptions;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public LoginController(ILoginService service, IMemoryCache memoryCache, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _service = service;
        _tokenOptions = new CustomTokenOptions();
        configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication").Bind(_tokenOptions);
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult GetToken()
    {
        //Returns a JWT token
        //This method returns a 404 Not Found
    }

    [Authorize(Policy="AllowedGroups")]
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        //This method works
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
var basePath = $("base").first().attr("href");

function login() {
  $("#btnLogin").attr("disabled", true);
  username = $("#username").val();
  password = $("#password").val();
  request = $.ajax({
    url: basePath + "api/Login/GetToken",
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }
  });

function logout() {
  request = $.ajax({
    url: basePath + "api/Login/Logout",
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.token()
    }
  }).then(function () {
    self.loggedIn(false);
    self.token("");
  });
}
```

Other things I've tried for debugging purposes:

- Deleting the contents of the GetToken() method and replacing it with `return StatusCode(200);`  This means that there's nothing inside the GetToken method that's responsible for the error.
- Commenting out the `UseAuthentication` and `Authorize` statements in my code.  The error still happens when authentication is off.
- Renaming the GetToken method to something else.

Comment: Did you use postman to test the GetToken url as well? Did that also return a 404? Also, console.log the "basePath" variable or check the request url in developer tools when running on the server to make sure it's hitting the URL you expect it to.

Comment: Can you also post the other methods and attributes in your `LoginController`? Also it might be a good idea to move the `[Authorize(Policy="AllowedGroups")]` at the controller level and allow anonymous on the ones you see fit.

Comment: GetToken returns a 404 in Postman as well, and developer tools shows that it's hitting the URL that I expect (hostname/AppName/api/Login/GetToken).  Those are the only two methods in LoginController, but I'll add the attributes.

Comment: Moving the [Authorize] to the controller level didn't change things.

Comment: The 30 seconds sounds like a default SQL Server connection limit. You could have issues with your identity provider that tries an invalid sql connection, times out and returns 404 instead of 500.

Comment: I haven't used attribute-based routing in Core but I vaguely remember reading something about routing conflicts that seemed similar. Try putting the action placeholder into the class-level attrib, `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` and change the method-level attribs to just `[HttpPost]`. Also, some parts of ASP.NET Core look for HTTP verbs (Get, Post, etc) as part of the method names, I'm not sure whether an `[HttpPost]` attrib would override that or whether it applies in classes derived from `Controller`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla put me onto the right track. The LoginService has a connection to a Proficy server that it's supposed to use for authentication.  This happens in the service's constructor, so the error happens before it ever gets to the controller action.  That's why it kept happening no matter what I changed.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @WictorZychla. The LoginService in the constructor was failing, so the error happened before it ever got to the controller action.